# Facebook API error - (#32) Page request limited reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, botlibre

I have a bot from Bot Libre connected to my Facebook page and Facebook Messenger.
The bot has its own Facebook app, that has been approved, and has been running for several month without issues.

But the last two days I suddenly get the error below any time I call a Facebook API,

```
message - (#32) Page request limited reached
code - 32
Relevant information for error recovery can be found on the Facebook Developers Document:
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors
```

I tried refreshing the bot page access token, but still get the same error?

When I look at the app, it only shows 14 API calls today... don't see how I can be hitting a limit.  How do you see the API calls/day for a Facebook page access token?

Anyone else have this issue or know anything about it?

Comment: It should be obvious that such a limit is designed in a way that you can not weasel your way around it by simply getting a new token ... that would make it pointless. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Comment: The limit is per page. Doesn't matter how many apps or how many access tokens your use.

Comment: but the app/page only used 14 API calls? how does that exceed a limit?

Comment: and how can it be working fine for months and just stop working today?

Comment: how can you see how many API were used for a page?

Answer (score 3):

Since July 11, 2016 Facebook has "improved" the Facebook Graph API rate limit **for page**.

## What's my current rate limit?

---

Now your **current rate limit** (current 24-hour window) is calculated using last 24-hour window number of engaged users.

Engagement includes **a click on the Page or Page content**.

**NOTE**: You can get this value with the [Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/insights) **page_engaged_users** metric.

## What's my current rate?

---

Your **current rate** is calculated by using:

- **Call count**
- **Total time used**
- **CPU time used**

You can check you current rate compared to your current rate limit on **your page** > **Insights** > **API** section:

```
https://www.facebook.com/<your-page-name>/insights/?section=navAPI
```

## What's my current "Call count" limit?

---

You can make **4800 calls for each engaged user** during a 24-hour period.

## What can I do?

---

1. **Wait to get more fans** to be able to get a higher rate limit.
2. Each Facebook Graph API response includes a **X-Page-Usage** header with *call_count*, *total_cputime* and *total_time* percentage  values (There is no header if the Page's utilization is effectively 0%). When any of these metrics exceed 100, the app managing that page will be rate limited. **Use that values to evaluate your API usage** so you can balance it and never get blocked. Example of page utilization header:

   ```
   X-Page-Usage : {'call_count' : 85, 'total_cputime' : 56, 'total_time' : 60}
   ```
3. If you still need a higher rate limit, consider **requesting a rate limit increase**.

   - Go to your App (not Page) dashboard:

     ```
     https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<your-api-ID>/dashboard/
     ```
   - Scroll down to the last block called "API limit at page level".
   - Select you page in the combobox.
   - Click on the "API Limit Increase Request" button. You'll be requested to fill a form including the reason for your app to reach the rate limit and why your app needs a higher rate limit.

## Detailed information

---

For more information, please see:

- [Improving Rate Limits for Page Management Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/06/16/page-level-rate-limits/) developers announcement.
- [API Graph Rate Limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) advanced documentation.

Comment: @PeterSmith Ok, thank you. After reading [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) I thought that it was correct, because they are asking about the same problem, but they have different questions about that.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced similar problem with new desktop app, please look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/06/16/page-level-rate-limits/). Also look at your app Page Level Rate Limiting regarding your page (select it in combobox).

Comment: thank you, finally found the Page API stats, you can't seem to get it from the developers console, you need to go to your page in fb, then click on 'Insites' then click on API... not easy to find

Comment: the page rate limit seems to only show the last 24 hour average, even though the drop down lets you select 7 days, but it show %650 for yesterday, no idea why but account for the limit being imposed, it is working again today, so I will track the bots API usage and wait and see

Comment: James, is correct this page is not easy to find. Following his instructions I was able to determine the problem. It appears that I had a twitter app and my new test app. That sent me over the limit. From what little I read, it looks like if you hit the API and it returns a error 32, that counts against you as well. (Could be wrong), anyways facebook is a pain.